# Error on socket even though socket is enabled in PHP.ini for OrientDB

Tags: php, xampp, orientdb

i need help with the problem I found. I use OrientDB and connect it with PHP, then i get the error as below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOrient\Exceptions\SocketException: Error 0 : The operation completed successfully in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\OrientSocket.php:91 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport.php(146): PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\OrientSocket->connect() 
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\Abstracts\Operation.php(76): PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport->getSocket() 
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport.php(223): PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\Abstracts\Operation->__construct(Object(PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport))
>
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport.php(161): PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport->operationFactory('PhpOrient\Proto...', Array) 
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\PhpOrient.php(247): PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\SocketTransport->execute('connect', Array)
>
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\coba.php(8): PhpOrient\PhpOrient->connect() 
> #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas\PhpOrient\src\PhpOrient\Protocols\Binary\OrientSocket.php on line 91

Here is the php file:

```
<?php
require "PhpOrient/vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOrient\PhpOrient;

$client = new PhpOrient( 'localhost', 2424 );
$client->username = 'root';
$client->password = '0r13ntDB';
$client->connect();
?>
```

and i already turn on sockets extension on php.ini :

```
; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See https://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
extension=xsl
```

maybe I missed something?

Comment: Yes, for extension=php_sockets.dll is already in the php\ext\ folder.

Answer (score 1):

it turns out that OrientDB does not support PHP version 8, when I change it to PHP version 7.x everything runs normally.

If you are using OrientDB don't forget to adjust the following bugs when installing:

> 1. require-dev.Ostico/phpdoc-md is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use ostico/phpdoc-md instead.
> 2. Root composer.json requires phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[dev-master]

Fixing :

> Open composer.json in your PhpOrient folder then :
>
> 1. Make changes to "Ostico/phpdoc-md" to "ostico/phpdoc-md" in "require-dev"
> 2. The removal of "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor" in "require-dev" was replaced by a manual installation of
>    https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/releases